# Joining tables using subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have some tables:
tableA (cola1, cola2, cola3, cola4, cola5)
tableB (colb1, colb2)
tableC (colc1, colc2, colc3)
tableA.cola2 refers to tableB.colb1
and tableA.cola3 refers to tableC.colc1
I want to retrieve data from all those tables, I have a query using join like this:

```
Select tableA.cola1, tableA.cola2, tableA.cola3, tableA.cola4, tableA.cola5, tableB.colb2, tableC.colc2, tableC.colc3
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.cola2 = tableB.colb1
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableA.cola3 = tableC.colc1
WHERE tableA.cola5 = 'something'
```

So, is it possible to write this query using subqueries instead of JOIN?
and what would be better? subqueries or JOIN?
A friend of mine told me that when you have large tables, JOIN is slow and requires a powerful computer, while subqueries is faster and doens't require a powerful computer to perform the selection. He said it's because subqueries return results based on something like addition, and JOIN reutrn results based on something like multiplication (I'm not good at English so I don't know how to put this, but hope you get the idea). I am new to this and I've tried to google but still can't understand that. Would anybody please spare sometime answer my question and explain this subquery vs JOIN thing to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: The MySQL query optimiser will likely treat both joins and subqueries the same. If performance is a concern, simply make sure the joined columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still don't get why people advised me to use sub-queries instead of Joins. And can you show me the how to re-write that Join above using sub-queries (just curious how to write it and make it run). Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
Select cola1, cola2, cola3, cola4, cola5, colb2, colc2, colc3,colb1, colb2,colc1, colc2, colc3 FROM
(Select cola1, cola2, cola3, cola4, cola5, colb2, colc2, colc3,colb1, colb2 FROM
(Select cola1, cola2, cola3, cola4, cola5, colb2, colc2, colc3 FROM tableA) as A
INNER JOIN 
(Select colb1, colb2 from tableB) as B
ON A.cola2 = B.colb1)as AB
INNER JOIN
(Select  colc1, colc2, colc3 From tableC) as C 
ON AB.cola3 = C.colc1
WHERE AB.cola5 = 'something'
```

Comment: Update the query..above take a check of it